# Why Datareader cannot be initialized?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

we use abstract keyword before classname to restric creating the instance of a class.

But datareader is not an abstract class,but we cant create instance of that..can you explain why?

I searched about it then I found it does not have constructor that's why we cannot create object but as per my knowledge if there is no constructor then compiler automatic create a default constructor.

Please help...

Comment: Normally *you* don't create the reader; you ask a command to do it *for* you. What is it that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`DbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an abstract class. If you mean [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, it has no public constructor, that's why you can't create an instance. It has only an [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) constructor (ILSpy):

```
// System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
internal SqlDataReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
{
    // ...
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> To create a `SqlDataReader`, you **must** call the `ExecuteReader` method of
>   the SqlCommand object, instead of directly using a constructor.

In general it is a good idea to avoid instantiating a `DataReader` since it needs to be created via `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` only.

Comment: we can do this 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader();' even sqlreader not having public constructor but have default constructor

Comment: @PranayRana: have you tried to compile? There is no default constructor, just a static constructor and the internal one that i've already mentioned.

Comment: ITs compile time error thanks for helping me to understand this...\

Comment: *Why* is it a good idea to avoid instantiating a `DataReader`?

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own class that implements `DbDataReader` and override the methods

```
public class InMemoryDbReader: DbDataReader
{
    ...
}
```