# The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors defined, Please check the code

Tags: c#

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors defined,
>   Please check the code
>   I can't fixed this problem
>
> When I am run this code I am faceing thisproblem in SqlDataReader dr =
>   new SqlDataReader();
>   The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors
>   defined, Please check the code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace PhotoGellaryy.Models
{
    public class PhotoGellary
    {

        public string strcn = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UploadImagesEntities"].ToString();

        public IList<UploadImagesViewModel>GetImages()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcn);
            List<UploadImagesViewModel> photogellary = new 
List<UploadImagesViewModel>();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select ImageID,ImageName from 
ImageUploadTbl";
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader();
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    UploadImagesViewModel objuploadimagesviewmodel = new 
UploadImagesViewModel();
                     //objuploadimagesviewmodel.ImageID = 
dr["ImageID"].ToString();
                     objuploadimagesviewmodel.ImageName = 
dr["ImageName"].ToString();
                    photogellary.Add(objuploadimagesviewmodel);
                }
                if(dr!= null)
                {


                    dr.Dispose();
                    dr.Close();
                }
                con.Close();
                return photogellary.ToList();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider pasting your code here instead of the image of the code!!! Thanks!!

Comment: [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks): "To create a `SqlDataReader`, you must call the `ExecuteReader` method of the `SqlCommand` object, instead of directly using a constructor."

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` and should each be in `using` blocks, then you won't need either of the `Close`s or the `Dispose` because the implicit Dispose will handle that for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169519/the-type-system-data-sqlclient-sqldatareader-has-no-constructors-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line with:

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And why we are not allowed to create an object of `SqlDataReader` for that have a look at [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21624216/7124761)